# Using the AVPlayer in swift (xcode 6), how can I implement automatic gain control (AGC) while playing remote files?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avplayer, volume

I absolutely need to play remote files in an iOS app I'm developing, so using AVPlayer seems to be my only option.  (I don't want to download/load files as NSData, then implement the AVAudioPlayer because this doesn't allow the files to start playing immediately.)  These remote files sometimes vary greatly in output volume from one to another.  How can I implement some form of automatic gain control for the AVPlayer?  It's seeming like it's not even possible.

Also: I've explored the MTAudioProcessingTap, but couldn't get it to work using information from the following blogs:

http://venodesigns.net/2014/01/08/recording-live-audio-streams-on-ios/

and

https://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

I'm open to any ideas that involve the AVPlayer.  Can it be done?   (Thanks in advance - cheers!)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How can you have automatic gain control on audio which you do not know the levels of beforehand? Levelling depends on scanning a track to find its maximum peak and increases all levels to bring this up to full volume.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was possible to do instantaneous normalization on an audio data stream without needing any file information.  For example, isn't the point of the MTAudioProcessingTap (discussed in the first blog link above) to connect to a raw audio data stream, process it, then feed the result to the output?  Also, applications in apple's app store take any audio source as input and process it on the fly to your liking.  Check out Boom for Mac OS X.  This same principle has to be possible for iOS.  Or maybe I'm completely wrong.  Thanks for the response, amergin! :)

Comment: Sorry Joe but I don't have the time to go into this much at the moment. There are basic laws of physics at play here. Unless you can either scan the track before playing it to find out the maximum amplitude or if the metadata handed to you at the start of streaming gives you the maximum amplitude I can't see how you can just start upping or downing values.

Comment: Got it.  Perhaps my understanding of how I thought it worked is just plain wrong.  Appreciate the response!  I plan on just normalizing the audio files themselves instead of trying to programmatically level audio levels while streaming.  Cheers!